# Mapping FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) Token to Custom UserID

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

My existing app has login and registration functionality. What I'm trying to achieve is mapping FCM token (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#kotlin+ktx) with my custom user ID on my server.

The main issue I have is that `onNewToken` in the service will be called even before my user registration is done, as soon as the app is installed/initialised. So, then I wouldn't be able to map it to my custom user Id.

I can generate a token whenever I want with `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener`, but then I would lose out if there was a change in the token. I don't want the `onNewToken` method to be triggered before the user has completed registration, or even in case it does, I don't want to make the API call to my backend server before registration. Any suggestions or links would be greatly beneficial. Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

### TLDR

I'm trying to create a mapping between my custom user ID and FCM tokens. Once user completes registration, I will share the token to my backend server. If the token changes, I will update the mapping with this new token. Any suggestions/guidelines on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that from javascript you send the User ID to Kotlin (app), then from the app you send the token and the user I with PHP to save it in the Database, I did that and it works.

#### script.js

```
function showAndroidToast() {
   Android.showToast("18");// ID de Usuario
}
showAndroidToast();
```

#### WebAppInterface.kt

```
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {

    /** Show a toast from the web page  */
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(id_usuario: String) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ID-Usuario>"+id_usuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.exception)
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }

            // Obtenga un nuevo token de registro de Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
            val token = task.result

            // MOSTRAR LOG Y TOAST
            //val msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token)
            val msg = "TOKENdesdeJavascript>$token"
            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, msg)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            // Todo ENVIA TOKEN Y USUARIO A LA BBDD
            val urlServer ="http://example.com/AP_RegistrarToken.php"

            val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlServer,
                Response.Listener<String> {
                    fun onResponse(response: String?) {
                        val mensaje = "Registro Satisfactorio TOKEN y USUARIO"
                        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, mensaje)
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError?) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error en la Conexión TOKEN y  USUARIO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }) {
                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params.put("id_usuario_kotlin",id_usuario)
                    params.put("token_kotlin", token)
                    return params
                }
            }

            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "SE REGISTRO EXITOSAMENTE")

            val requestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext)
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest)


        }) // FirebaseMessaging

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SE REGISTRO EXITOSAMENTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } // FIN FUNCION

}
```

In this way you send the token to the database, only when the user is already registered.

I hope it helps you. I did this yesterday and it works and like you, I'm working on an app with webview to send notifications.

Comment: Thanks, so what I did was store the token and a boolean flag `syncedWithBackend` in SharedPrefs whenever I got a new token from the listener. So on Login (and every time the user visits a specific screen) I check if this is false and make the API call to sync the FCM token with backend. On a successful API response, I set this to true so as to avoid making an API call again.

Comment: Additionally, I created a worker to upload the FCM token when a new token is generated when the app is in the background (obviously enforcing login checks).

Comment: How to detect Kotlin Refreshed new Token when the app is in in the background ? Can you give me some example? I want to learn more.